# Celery: different settings for task_acks_late per worker / add custom option to celery

Tags: python, django, celery

This question is a follow up of [django + celery: disable prefetch for one worker, Is there a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290045/django-celery-disable-prefetch-for-one-worker-is-there-a-bug)

I had a problem with celery (see the question that I follow up) and in order to resolve it I'd like to have two celery workers with -concurrency 1 each but with two different settings of task_acks_late.

My current approach is working, but in my opinion not very beautiful. I am doing the following:

in `settings.py` of my django project:

```
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = os.environ.get("LACK", "False") == "True"
```

This allows me to start the celery workers with following commands:

```
LACK=True celery -A miniclry worker --concurrency=1 -n w2 -Q=fast,slow --prefetch-multiplier 1 
celery -A miniclry worker --concurrency=1 -n w1 -Q=fast
```

What would be more intuitive would be if I could do something like:

```
celery -A miniclry worker --concurrency=1 -n w2 -Q=fast,slow --prefetch-multiplier 1 --late-ack=True
celery -A miniclry worker --concurrency=1 -n w1 -Q=fast --late-ack=False
```

I found [Initializing Different Celery Workers with Different Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981155/initializing-different-celery-workers-with-different-values) but don't understand how to embed this in my django / celery context. In which files would I have to add the code that's adding an argument to the parser and how could I use the custom param to modify  task_acks_late of the celery settings.

**Update:**
Thanks to @Greenev's answer I managed to add custom options to celery. However it seems, that changing the config with this mechanism 'arrives too late' and the chagne is not taken into account.

Comment: some are celery cron jobs, some are tasks triggered by an action on the web server (trigger by a django post requet)

The celery processes will be either started by uwsgi or by supervisor. I didn't decide so far.

Comment: @CalebGoodman. No reaction from you. Was my answer not what you expected?
Did I miss the intention of your question?

Comment: You can annotate each task with acks_late, and turn it on/off...

Comment: @DejanLekic In fact I want fast tasks to be acknowledged early in one worker and late in the other, so annotating tasks is not the solution as it doesn't know which worker will pick it up.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from having two tasks (the second just calls the first...) with different acks_late settings...

Comment: @DejanLekic Pls read again the question and look at the question which trigger this question. The issue is, that one task should have different acks_late setting depending on the worker which picked it up. So the choice of ack_late or not ack_late depends on the worker it is running on so a configuration by task is not appropriate.

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish that is via task_queues and task_routes. [Reference](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#routing-tasks)

Comment: @DejanLekic: I do have a solution that is working (It solves   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290045/django-celery-disable-prefetch-for-one-worker-is-there-a-bug )

However  the solution (using  env var being read in django settings and run one celery worker with one value and the other celery worker with an other value of that env var) is not the most elegant one.

I am using routes and one worker treating with early_ack for  fast queue and the other worker  treating fast and slow queue with late_ack.

Greenev's answer would be perfect but unfortunately doesn't work so far.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution here is to provide `acks_late=True` as an argument of the `shared_task` decorator, given your code from the prior question:

```
@shared_task(acks_late=True)
def task_fast(delay=0.1):
    logger.warning("fast in")
    time.sleep(delay)
    logger.warning("fast out")
```

UPD. I haven't got `task_acks_late` to be set using this approach, but you could add a command line argument as follows.

You've already linked to a solution. I can't see any django specifics here, just put the `parser.add_argument` code to where you have defined your `app`, given your code from the prior question, you would have something like this:

```
app = Celery("miniclry", backend="rpc", broker="pyamqp://")
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

def add_worker_arguments(parser):
    parser.add_argument('--late-ack', default=False)

app.user_options['worker'].add(add_worker_arguments)
```

Then you could access your argument value in `celeryd_init` signal handler

```
@celeryd_init.connect
def configure_worker(sender=None, conf=None, options=None, **kwargs):
    conf.task_acks_late = options.get('late-ack') # get custom argument value from options
```

Comment: Thanks @Greenev.

IN fact this would be a solution, but not in the contect of my initial question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290045/django-celery-disable-prefetch-for-one-worker-is-there-a-bug )  where I would like, that the same task is either executed with acks_late=True or with acks_late=False depending on the worker it was handled with.

One worker should handle with acks_late in order to have the best trhoughput,
the other worker should have less throughput, but at least help a little to use the other CPU.

Comment: The nicer solution would probably be to add a command line argument to celery.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer.
Will  try out, but the indentation in your answer seems to be wrong, I think there's also one useless trailing ','

Comment: following line is also missing.
It's perhaps obvious for some people, but probably better to add it:
`from celery.signals import celeryd_init`

can this be in the file project/celery.py ?
I have the impression it can, but want to be sure about potential boundary cases (issues with import order)

Comment: Finally I tried the suggestion of using the celeryd_init signal to modify the conf.
Adding an option works fine, the the function connected to ceryd_Init is called.

However it seems, that the conf is changed too late, as the changes are not taken into account.

In fact the Django settings were already imported before. (and celery was probably already configured before (at least the late_ack)

Any other idea?

So at the moment I seem to be stuck with my ugly env var trick

Comment: you are right, we have only `task_acks_late` being set here, but not `task.late_ack`, so it seems like we need to dive into the celery source code to solve this issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the time being I'll use an env var to solve the issue, but I'd really like to implement a `--late-ack` option. So I'd be curious whether, when there would be a fix. So pls keep me updated on this issue.

Comment: Now question to the SO community. What to do with this question? It seems, that at the moment, there is no other solution than what I suggested already in my question.

There is one upvote to Greenev\s answer, but at the moment it is not working.

It very probably will with a newer version of celery or some minor modification / monkey patch.

If I get no answer from you, then I'll just wait until there is a working answer, and then upvote / check the answer.

Comment: Any progress about this issue?
Is there perhaps an official issue / enhancement for this?
If yes, we could add a link to this question till the issue is fixed